# DOM nodes null in chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise

I have a chrome extension where I'm trying to navigate the DOM beginning at the clicked element, with the following content script:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log(selection);
    const currentNode = selection.anchorNode;
    console.log(currentNode);​
}
```

On the first click, `currentNode` is always null.  On subsequent clicks it is the selected node, as expected.

In the debug window the logged `selection` variable shows the selection object with all members null, but they are evaluated if I expand the object with the drop down arrow next to it.

It looks like something is being asynchronously evaluated, which I gather is usually handled with promises in JavaScript. Neither of the calls I make return a promise that I can wait on though.

Am I missing something obvious here? How do I force evaluation of the selection's members the first time round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the `mousedown` event is firing too early.

Try changing it to a `click` or `mouseup` event instead of `mousedown`.

Also, on a `click` event you have access to `event.target`, which will be the node that was clicked on. `window.getSelection()` is probably not what you're looking for here if your goal is simply to navigate starting from the clicked element.

Comment: Both of those work, thanks. Looks like `event.target` is the way to go

Comment: That appears to be the correct event to use if you are interested in the text being selected, but that's not what the question is about. Could you provide some more information if you think that's the right thing to do?